# Letting drawings ignore a contour without drawing over the label

Tags: tikz-pgf, contour

I used the contour package to label an edge. I wish for other edges, to not be interrupted by the contour around the label. This can be achieved by just drawing those edges after the labelled one. But this draws over the label which makes it harder to read it if I use different colors. The following example gives me this

[image]

I do want the black line to be interrupted and the grey line to be continuous. However, the grey line is drawn over x which I do not desire. How can I draw x over the grey line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.8pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=0.50] {\contour{white}{$x$}};
\draw[-, black!30] (1,1) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. If you draw a line after a node, it will be drawn over it. Nothing the `contour` package can do about it. You can give the node a name and use it `(1,-1) -- (<name>) -- (1, -1)`. Instead of the `contour` package you can also just use `fill=white` with the node. Is there a bigger context for your diagrams?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try that. But only in this minimal example the value for the node position is easily readable. The context is that I want to draw a graph and label only edges that are originating from one vertex by interrupting the edges for which I thought the contour package might be helpful. All other edges shall have a lighter color and not be interrupted, which causes the problem that some go over the labels making them harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code (manual)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \path % place the node first
    (0,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=.5, inner sep=+.15em] (x) {$x$}
    [behind path]
    % then draw the lines
    % • the black line use the node as a coordinate
    %   so that it actually stops at its border
    %   (could also be a separate path, doesn't need to be an edge)
    (0,0) edge[to path=--(x)--(\tikztotarget)] (2,0)
    % • the gray line doesn't use the node name
    %   but since “behind path” is used
    %   it will be behind the node
    %   (which is by default “in front of path”)
    (1,1) edge[black!30] (1,-1);
\end{document}
```

### Code (using `tikz-ext`'s `ext.nodes` library's `node on line`)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.nodes}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw (0,0) to [node on line] node[pos=.5, inner sep=+.15em] (x) {$x$} (2,0)
    [behind path] (1,1) edge[black!30] (1, -1);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Of course, just drawin the gray line first and then node and black line later works, too: `\tikz{\draw[black!30] (1,1) -- (1, -1); \draw (0,0) to [node on line] node[pos=.5, inner sep=+.15em] (x) {$x$} (2,0);}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can leave the node empty and add the content later:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.8pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=0.50] (x){};
\draw[-, black!30] (1,1) -- (1,-1);
\node at (x){\contour{white}{$x$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want the gray line to cut through the x (which imho doesn't look good):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.8pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[fill=white,inner sep=0pt,pos=0.50] (x){\phantom{$x$}};
\draw[-, black!30] (1,1) -- (1,-1);
\node at (x){$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one still interrupts the grey line unfortunately. But I had a similar idea that worked

Comment: that sounds odd, but I added an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which is more a work around. I can draw a white label first and then draw over that label after.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.8pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=0.50] {\contour{white}{\textcolor{white}{$x$}}};
\draw[-, black!30] (1,1) -- (1,-1);
\path (0,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=0.50] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Feel free to post a more elegent way if you have an idea.